# How to extract text from inside div tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Im trying to get the numbers from inside the div tag from the following html content `<div class="nowPrice"><div class="showPrice" style="color: rgb(14, 203, 129);">47,864.58</div><div class="subPrice">$47,864.58</div></div>`

What I need is

> $47,864.5

Ive tried multiple ways of trying to extract this but i either keep getting errors or it returns an empty list as [] or none in the output
This is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq



my_url = 'https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT?layout=basic'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


ff = page_soup.find("div", class_= "subPrice").get_text()
print(ff)
```

This outputs None

EDIT:
I tried using Selenium to get the data and it works

Comment: Price value is updating and rendering using `JS` so from `bs4` you can not find its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In edited question data load from `javascript` and you need library like `selenium` and you can't get data with `BeautifulSoup`.

**This answer for old question:**

If you have multiple `class="subPrice"`, you can use `find_all()` and get price with `.text` like below:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<div class="nowPrice">
    <div class="showPrice" style="color: rgb(14, 203, 129);">47,864.58</div>
    <div class="subPrice">$47,864.58</div>
    <div class="subPrice">$57,864.58</div>
    <div class="subPrice">$67,864.58</div>
    <div class="subPrice">$77,864.58</div>
</div>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
for sp in soup.find_all("div",class_="subPrice"):
    print(sp.text)
```

output:

```
$47,864.58
$57,864.58
$67,864.58
$77,864.58
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

What you can do price can be fetch from script tag which reflect in `title` of the page but it is static not dynamic

Code:

```
data=page_soup.find("script",attrs={"id":"__APP_DATA"}).contents[0]
import json
data=json.loads(data)

price=data['appProps']['metaData']['title'].split(" |")[0]
price
```

Output:

```
'47916.17'
```

**Old:**

```
html="""<div class="nowPrice"><div class="showPrice" style="color: rgb(14, 203, 129);">47,864.58</div><div class="subPrice">$47,864.58</div></div>"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
soup.find("div",class_="subPrice").get_text()
```

Output:

```
'$47,864.58'
```

Comment: Your code outputs this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: can you share your URL please it is according to HTML given by you

Comment: Yes I also tried extracting it directly from the title and it worked. however I wanted to know from a learning point of view wether it is possible to extract the value directly from the div tag or not?

Comment: see  value is changing in fractions so from `bs4` you will not get updated value try with API to get latest data